# Delegate issue between Objective-C and Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I'm just about to get into the basics of Swift, Objective-C & C++. I'm trying to build a bridge between Objective-C & Swift & set up a suitable delegate (MyDelegate).

The code below is working quite fine but I got some problems calling the Swift function `callbackInteger()` from a static function like:

MyFile.mm:

```
static void test() {
    // how to call callbackInteger?
}
```

MyFile.mm:

```
- (void)callbackToSwift:(int)testInteger {
    if (self.delegate != nil) {
        [self.delegate callbackInteger: testInteger];
    }
}
```

MyDelegate.h:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) callbackInteger: (int) testInteger;
@end
```

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate {
    func callbackInteger(_ testInteger: Int) {
       print("testInteger: \(testInteger)");
    }
}
```

**Note**: I really have no idea how to achieve a call to the callbackInteger function using the delegate call.

Comment: It is objectiveC++, so I added the tag objectiveC & the tag C++. I‘m pretty sure I did nothing wrong:) @hlt

Comment: `func callbackInteger` is an _instance_ function. You need to refer to a particular ViewController instance in order to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A protocol is nothing more that a set of requirements (methods) that a class has to implement. We say that a class conforms to a protocol.

So in your static function `test()`, you can't call the method of the protocol if you don't have an instance/object around (here a `ViewController`). A working way (but not necessary a beautiful one) would be to store somewhere (as a global variable for example) an instance of ViewController in order to reuse it in the function.

Something like this :

```
// Top of your file
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
// other headers...

id<MyDelegate> globalDelegate;

static void test() {
    [globalDelegate callbackInteger:42];
}

// rest of your file
```

There are plenty of resources about protocols and the delegation pattern like [this guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html). Read carefully how they use it in Cocoa & Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Sounds like a really good solution - but for me it doesn't seems to call the Swift function using `[globalDelegate callbackInteger:42];`. Wether theres occurring an error nor the `callbackInteger` gets called. No idea whats the problem.

Comment: Obviously you would have to set the value of `globalDelegate` somewhere, like in your `callbackToSwift` method.